# How to use js dom manipulation on elements accessed by using ViewChild

Tags: javascript, angular

My **component.html**:

```
<div #container>
    <div id="target">
        something
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" (click)="onClick()">Click</button>
```

My **component.ts**:

```
@ViewChild('container', {static: false}) container;
  onClick() {
    console.log(this.container.nativeElement.getElementById('target'));
  }
```

So I want to use javascript dom methods on the element I am getting using `ViewChild` it says:

> container.nativeElement.getElementById` isn't a function

How can I solve this and is there an alternate approach ?

Comment: `getElementById` is available on the `document` and not on any native element. `container.nativeElement` is your html element on which you can perform operations

Comment: So if I want to get an element inside my `container` by id, what should I do?

Comment: It will be one level oh HTML as in your example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the element by using query selector

this.container.nativeElement.querySelector("#target").

Comment: awesome dude, any idea why `getElementById` isn't working I mean `querySelector` is also js right?

Comment: getElementById is available on javascript DOM element , unfortunately not on angular element.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get element by id you can use :

```
document.getElementById('target') as HTMLElement;
```

Read this article https://medium.com/@madhavmahesh/handling-dom-level-events-in-angular-with-typescript-dd7cda5f8307

Comment: I know this, I want to get the element inside the container, not on the overall document.